# Why is Meteor update overriding existing properties in my documents?

Tags: javascript, meteor

Something's not working for me with Meteor update.

If I run:

```
Countries.insert({name: 'China'});
```

I get a new document in my Countries collection, with name 'China' - as you'd expect.

But when I then run:

```
Countries.update({name: 'China'}, {population: '1 billion'});
```

The document now has a population property, but it's lost its name property. It's definitely the same document - same id.

I thought I was following this syntax:

```
collection.update(selector, modifier, [options], [callback])
```

straight out of the Meteor Docs.

I've also tried the update using the id string of the document (rather than the selector) in the update command, but the same thing happens.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this help

```
Countries.update({ name: 'China' } , { $set : { population: '1 billion' }});
```

This adds the key:value if it doesn't already exist for the doc. I have also successfully used the following to add a value to multiple docs.

```
Countries.update({ continent: 'Asia' } , { $set : { food: 'delicious' } } , { multi : true } );
```

This would add food:delicious to all countries with the continent Asia.

Comment: **See also:** [Modifier operations](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-ModifierOperations) and the rest on that page.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I see now that the need for $-operators is there in the docs. I just missed it :-(